# Changing the background color of a custom combination input-select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Using jQuery,

How can I change the background of both my input box and select box when a user either clicks on the drop down or puts their cursor in the input box?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
#refdocs_select { 
    left: expression(this.previousSibling.offsetLeft); 
    width: expression(this.previousSibling.offsetWidth);  
    clip: expression("rect(2px auto 20px " + (this.previousSibling.offsetWidth - 20) + "px)"); 
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#refdocs_wrapper {
    border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 179px;
    height: 20px;
}
#refdocs_input {
    border: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: 174px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 2px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="refdocs_wrapper">
        <input id="refdocs_input" type="text" ><select id="refdocs_select"></select>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/jyr8r/

A new class is also added for style.

```
$(function(){
    $('input#refdocs_input,select#refdocs_select').focus(function(){
       $('input#refdocs_input,select#refdocs_select').addClass('inFocus'); 
    })
    .blur(function(){
        $('input#refdocs_input,select#refdocs_select').removeClass('inFocus'); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can attach events to your elements and run a function that changes the backgrounds. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3XjyR/1/)

```
function changeBG()
{
    $("#refdocs_input").css("background-color","#FF0000");
    $("#refdocs_select").css("background-color","#FF0000");
}
$("#refdocs_input").hover(changeBG);
$("#refdocs_select").click(changeBG);
```

if you need to trigger when the user clicks the input box you should change `hover` to `focus`. and if you need to change the trigger on select, to when the user selects a new option, you should change `click` to `change`

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to import the jQuery library:

```
<script src='jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Next, you'll want to assign a CSS class to both the input and the select element:

```
<input id="refdocs_input" class="bg-change" type="text" ><select id="refdocs_select" class="bg-change"></select>
```

Finally, define a click function for all of those elements that calls the jQuery css(propertyName, value) function on each element with that background.

```
    $(".bg-change").click(function(){
        $(".bg-change").css("background-color","yellow");
    });
```

Here's the complete source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
#refdocs_select { 
    left: expression(this.previousSibling.offsetLeft); 
    width: expression(this.previousSibling.offsetWidth);  
    clip: expression("rect(2px auto 20px " + (this.previousSibling.offsetWidth - 20) + "px)"); 
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#refdocs_wrapper {
    border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 179px;
    height: 20px;
}
#refdocs_input {
    border: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: 174px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 2px;
}
</style>
<script src='jquery.min.js'></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="refdocs_wrapper">
        <input id="refdocs_input" class="bg-change" type="text" ><select id="refdocs_select" class="bg-change"></select>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(".bg-change").click(function(){
        $(".bg-change").css("background-color","yellow");
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```